# Redux getState does not work, but useSelector does

Tags: redux, redux-persist

**SOLVED**

We found a literally two minutes after posting this question...
Our solution was this:

```
let state:any;
store.subscribe(() => {
    state = store.getState();
});
```

I'm building a React app with Redux and redux-persist. I have a problem with accessing Redux state outside a React component. If I subscribe to the store and console log the state it shows the correct state with data inside it, but when I console log the state outside (`const state = store.getState();`
) the subscribe arrow function (`store.subscribe(() => console.log(store.getState()))`) the data inside the store is empty. And when I use the useSelector hook, inside a React component, it works fine. This is a really weird bug since it appeared two weeks after I wrote the code using the store outside a React component. Has anyone had a similar bug?

This is my Redux config.

```
// Redux.
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";

// Redux-thunk.
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

// Reducers.
import reducers from "../reducers";

// Storage.
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage' // defaults to localStorage for web

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage,
}
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducers);
const composeEnhancers =
    (window["__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__"] as typeof compose) ||
    compose;
const middleWare = applyMiddleware(thunk);
const store = createStore(persistedReducer,  composeEnhancers(middleWare));
const persistor = persistStore(store)

export {store, persistor};
```

Comment: Your problem description seems a bit odd.  Where and how are you needing to access the Redux store outside of React?  And the listed solution seems very wrong.  Declaring `state` as a variable outside the subscribe callback should _not_ affect behavior, because `getState()` always returns a reference to whatever the current state value is.    Can you add more details on what you're actually trying to do, how, and why?

Comment: We need to access state outsite React to compare a websockets message with the current state in redux to see if we need to dispatch the message, because otherwise it will dispatch to Redux every second.

Comment: Consider [handling the websocket in a middleware](https://redux.js.org/faq/code-structure#where-should-websockets-and-other-persistent-connections-live) instead.  That's the general recommended place for using websockets in Redux, and it also has access to `getState`.